# Use Google Forms for Sociometry

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms

I wonder if it is possible to use Google Forms to gather Sociometry responses.

See this picture as an example:

[image: Sociometry - required table formation]

Clarification:
I want to create many rows per a single responder (see in my picture, there are 5 rows for responder 1, which represent each of the 5 Peers the responder needs to rank) . The second issue, is that the population always changes (responder 1 needs to rank 5 people, while responder 2 needs only 4)

Comment: Welcome. Yes it is.

Comment: @marikamitsos- I wonder if you can please provide more details on how to do so. Thanks.

Comment: Have you ever tried creating a Google Form? If not, please do so, see the results and if still in trouble let us know.

Comment: @marikamitsos- I did and I asked the forum as I don't know how to create many rows per a single responder (see in my picture, there are 5 rows for responder 1, which represent each of the 5 Peers the responder needs to rank) . The second issue, is that the population always changes (responder 1 needs to rank 5 people, while responder 2 needs only 4).

Comment: Please share a test form and it's response sheet along with some already given test replies  Also, do read how to and [share the test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped. As for the explanations in your comment, please [edit] your question and add them there.

Answer (score 0):

#### Just create a form and link it to your sheet.

I think you have already done this, but just in case:

- create a new form.
- link the responses to a spreadsheet.

#### How to identify the responder

Unless you are in a workspace account and all the responders are also in a workspace account there is no way to [identify the responder](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getactiveuser). The only way that you can do this is to ask the responder in the form for their "Responder ID". The only field that will be populated automatically will be the timestamp.

#### How to get multiple rows per response

The simple way is to simply get the participants to fill out the response multiple times. The more complex way is to look into [Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script) to construct forms based on a certain criteria, though this sounds like it will probably be complex to do in this way. Maybe you would be interested in building an Apps Script [web app](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/web) with which you could build an html form. That will probably give you more flexibility, though it will be a bit more work to set up.

#### How to organize your sheet so that all Responder IDs are sorted.

You can do this manually by [filtering or sorting](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) the data. Alternatively you can look into Apps Script to do this process automatically every few minutes or hours, depending on what you need it for.